# How to hit a http URL from PL/SQL procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

I am creating an Oracle job where I need to hit a procedure for every 30 minutes,

Inside the procedure, I want to hit a HTTP URL so behind that a java program will execute.

**Approach :**

```
declare 
 req   UTL_HTTP.REQ;
BEGIN
 req := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST('http://dev.xxx.com/yyy/zzz/aaa/triggerJob');
 dbms_output.put_line('hitting');
EXCEPTION
 WHEN UTL_HTTP.END_OF_BODY THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('exception');
END;
```

DBMS OUTPUT is hitting

-- But it is not hitting actually!

**Approach 2**

```
declare 
 req   UTL_HTTP.REQ;
 resp  UTL_HTTP.RESP;
BEGIN
 req := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST('http://dev.xxx.com/yyy/zzz/aaa/triggerJob');
 UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(req, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0');
 resp := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(req);
UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(resp);
 dbms_output.put_line('hitting');

EXCEPTION
 WHEN UTL_HTTP.END_OF_BODY THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('exception');
END;
```

With this, I am getting below errors while executing.

[image]

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? Have you granted pertinent access privileges?

Comment: @APC Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition, Yeah I have all the privileges. Read/Write/Update/Insert and ACL as well.

Comment: Presumably you have testing sending a GET Request to the URL through some normal web service mechanism, SOAPUI, whatever?

Comment: @APC I am hitting the URL in browser 'http://dev.xxx.com/yyy/zzz/aaa/triggerJob', it is absolutely working fine.

Comment: @APC Any clue on this.

Comment: Although you (possibly) could do it, you probably shouldn't. Use the database only for what it's good at: storing data. Use app code to combine different services.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a `get_response` to actually perform the request; otherwise its only prepared ;) ; another good practice is to set the http headers...

```
declare 
 req   UTL_HTTP.REQ;
BEGIN
 req := UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST('http://dev.xxx.com/yyy/zzz/aaa/triggerJob');
 UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(req, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0');
 UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(req);

 dbms_output.put_line('hitting');

EXCEPTION
 WHEN UTL_HTTP.END_OF_BODY THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('exception');
END;
```

more  in [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_http.htm#CHDBIGIF)

Comment: Please check approach 2(Suggested by you) at an above-updated question.

Comment: So this means you have to open another question. First issue is solve. Now you have to do something to enable your database to access the remote server (is it really http, or is it https??)

Comment: It is HTTP:// request.